# Phonegap/Cordova Capture Images possible without notification confirm?

Tags: android, cordova

I am currently using `navigator.device.capture.captureImage`.

Is it possible to somehow get at this so that the confirm dialog doesn't popup after every picture capture? As it is it takes a pic, brings up the confirm dialog, temporarily returns to the app for a second and then relaunches the camera.

Ideally I'd like to be able to snap multiple pics in one go like the native camera app and then exit the camera and deal with the captureSuccess callback.

I found the following on the [plugins git page](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture/blob/master/src/android/Capture.java): Would it be as easy as deleting the if clause `if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)` if I could figure out someother way of error checking?

```
 private void captureImage() {
    // Save the number of images currently on disk for later
    this.numPics = queryImgDB(whichContentStore()).getCount();

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    // Specify file so that large image is captured and returned
    File photo = new File(getTempDirectoryPath(), "Capture.jpg");
    try {
        // the ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE is run under different credentials and has to be granted write permissions 
        createWritableFile(photo);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        this.fail(createErrorObject(CAPTURE_INTERNAL_ERR, ex.toString()));
        return;
    }
    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));

    this.cordova.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin) this, intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
}


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent intent) {

    // Result received okay
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        etc
```

Thanks in advance